# What is the advantage of using multiple scanners?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

What is the advantage or use of using multiple scanner objects in a program?

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
```

as opposed to something like

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

in the same program.

Comment: There's no advantage to the second bit of code, and  in fact there is some risk, risk if you close one Scanner (and thus the `System.in`) before the other Scanner is done using it.

Comment: Is there a reason to or is it just preference?

Comment: Is there a reason for what? I see no reason to prefer code block number 2.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see no advantage to the second bit of code:

```
Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

and  in fact there is some risk, risk if you close one Scanner (and thus the `System.in`) before the other Scanner is done using it.

Instead, I can definitely see using more than one Scanner at times, but only one primary Scanner linking to `System.in`. Other Scanners can parse a line obtained. For example, use the main Scanner to get each line of text, and then use a second Scanner that has been fed the individual lines to parse the information held in the lines.

e.g.,

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = sc.nextLine();
    Scanner lineScanner = new Scanner(line);
    //.... parse line...
    lineScanner.close();
}
sc.close();
```

Comment: Of course, if that's all you're doing with the outer `Scanner`, you should replace it with a `BufferedReader`, for greatly improved performance.